# Tic Tac Toe game in Java OOP

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, game, tic-tac-toe

I have written a simple GUI Tic Tac Toe Application and since this is my first shot, I think it can be improved a lot.

Please tell me what you think about it and what you see I made wrong so I can avoid those mistakes the next time.

Is there code redundancy I don't see? Is everything declared and implemented at its right place?

Earlier I wrote a console based game and then tried to convert it in to object oriented based. I am not sure if this can be called object oriented because I have a little knowledge about object oriented structure as I am a beginner.

[image: Game]

**Main Class**

```
package tic_tac_adv;

public class Tic_Tac_Adv {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Main CLass

    Control C = new Control(); 

}

}
```

**Control Class**

```
package tic_tac_adv;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Control extends JFrame {

/*
this is the main controler that controls
and combines different components of the game.
*/ 

private Board GameBoard; //Board and Button
private Tools TButtons; // Exit and Reset

Control() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    GameBoard = new Board();
    TButtons = new Tools();

    TButtons.SetObject(GameBoard);

    add(GameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(TButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(350, 350);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

**Board Class**

```
   package tic_tac_adv;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JButton B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9; // Buttons
private GameArray GArray; // Class with Array
private boolean Player = false;
private int PlayerMark = 1;

/*
 Player is the Current players turn. if false player 1 will play else player 2
 PlayerMark is to set number to the array "1" for player 1 and "2" for player 2
 */
Board() {

    // creates the panel
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

    B1 = new JButton("");
    B2 = new JButton("");
    B3 = new JButton("");
    B4 = new JButton("");
    B5 = new JButton("");
    B6 = new JButton("");
    B7 = new JButton("");
    B8 = new JButton("");
    B9 = new JButton("");

    SetGame();

    add(B1);
    add(B2);
    add(B3);
    add(B4);
    add(B5);
    add(B6);
    add(B7);
    add(B8);
    add(B9);

    B1.addActionListener(this);
    B2.addActionListener(this);
    B3.addActionListener(this);
    B4.addActionListener(this);
    B5.addActionListener(this);
    B6.addActionListener(this);
    B7.addActionListener(this);
    B8.addActionListener(this);
    B9.addActionListener(this);

}

public void SetGame() {

    GArray = new GameArray(this);

    DefaultText();
    DisableAll(true);


    Player = false; // default Value
    PlayerMark = 1; // default Value
}

public void Reset() {

    SetGame(); // To Reset the Game

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E) {

    JButton Pressed = (JButton) E.getSource();

    /*
     if any button is pressed the value is sent to GameArray class
     */
    if (Pressed == B1) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(0, 0, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);     // chaneg button text to "X" or "O" based on player turn
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player); // Swithch Turns
        ButtonDisabler(B1); // Disable pressed Button

    } else if (Pressed == B2) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(0, 1, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(B2);
    } else if (Pressed == B3) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(0, 2, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(B3);

    } else if (Pressed == B4) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(1, 0, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(B4);

    } else if (Pressed == B5) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(1, 1, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(B5);

    } else if (Pressed == B6) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(1, 2, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(B6);
    } else if (Pressed == B7) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(2, 0, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(B7);
    } else if (Pressed == B8) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(2, 1, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(B8);
    } else if (Pressed == B9) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(2, 2, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(B9);
    }

}

public int SwithTurn(boolean last) {

    // if the past player was false(player 1) then swith to true(player 2)
    System.out.println();

    if (last == true) {
        Player = false;
        return 1;

    } else if (last == false) {
        Player = true;
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }

}

public void ButtonDisabler(JButton Btn) {

    Btn.setEnabled(false); // Disable Button

}

public void DisableAll(boolean Opp) {

    // Disable  All Buttons
    B1.setEnabled(Opp);
    B2.setEnabled(Opp);
    B3.setEnabled(Opp);
    B4.setEnabled(Opp);
    B5.setEnabled(Opp);
    B6.setEnabled(Opp);
    B7.setEnabled(Opp);
    B8.setEnabled(Opp);
    B9.setEnabled(Opp);

}

public void SetText(JButton Btn, boolean Play) {

    if (Play == true) {
        Btn.setText("O");
    } else if (Play == false) {
        Btn.setText("X");
    }

}

public void DefaultText(){

    B1.setText("");
    B2.setText("");
    B3.setText("");
    B4.setText("");
    B5.setText("");
    B6.setText("");
    B7.setText("");
    B8.setText("");
    B9.setText("");

}


}
```

**Array Class**

```
package tic_tac_adv;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameArray {

/*

Class for Array

*/

private Board Brd;
private int GameArr[][];
private boolean Turn;
private JButton Pressed;

GameArray(Board B) {

    GameArr = new int[3][3];

    Brd = B;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            GameArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

}

public void ArrayInitialize(int i, int j, int Marker) {

    //Set Data sent by Action listener in Board

    GameArr[i][j] = Marker;
    WinCheck(Marker);
}


public void WinCheck(int Marker) {

    // if the specified array indexs contain a certain Maker (1,2) on winning pattrens then announce winner

    if ((GameArr[0][0] == Marker && GameArr[0][1] == Marker && GameArr[0][2] == Marker) || (GameArr[1][0] == Marker && GameArr[1][1] == Marker && GameArr[1][2] == Marker) || (GameArr[2][0] == Marker && GameArr[2][1] == Marker && GameArr[2][2] == Marker)) {

        if (Marker == 1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Brd, "CONGRATULATIONS : Player 1 (Winner)");

        } else if (Marker == 2) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Brd, "CONGRATULATIONS : Player 2 (Winner)");

        }

        Brd.DisableAll(false);

    } else if ((GameArr[0][0] == Marker && GameArr[1][0] == Marker && GameArr[2][0] == Marker) || (GameArr[0][1] == Marker && GameArr[1][1] == Marker && GameArr[2][1] == Marker) || (GameArr[0][2] == Marker && GameArr[1][2] == Marker && GameArr[2][2] == Marker)) {

        if (Marker == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Brd, "CONGRATULATIONS : Player 1 (Winner)");

        } else if (Marker == 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Brd, "CONGRATULATIONS : Player 2 (Winner)");

        }

        Brd.DisableAll(false);

    } else if ((GameArr[0][0] == Marker && GameArr[1][1] == Marker && GameArr[2][2] == Marker) || (GameArr[2][0] == Marker && GameArr[1][1] == Marker && GameArr[0][2] == Marker)) {

        if (Marker == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Brd, "CONGRATULATIONS : Player 1 (Winner)");

        } else if (Marker == 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Brd, "CONGRATULATIONS : Player 2 (Winner)");

        }
        Brd.DisableAll(false);

    }

}

}
```

**Tool Class**

```
package tic_tac_adv;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tools extends JPanel {

private JButton Exit, Reset;
private Board Brd;

Tools() {

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Exit = new JButton("Exit");
    Reset = new JButton("Reset");

    Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    Reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            Brd.Reset();

        }

    });

    add(Exit);
    add(Reset);
}

public void SetObject(Board B) {

    Brd = B;

}

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mathew had some great responses, but I'd like to explain a little more about using for loops. If you take a look at your `Board()` code right now, you might notice how a lot of the code is the same - when you make the `JButton`s, for example, you call `new JButton("")` nine times in a row. In general, having a lot of code that all looks the same or is copy-pasted is a bad idea. You can use a for loop with an array to clean this up a lot. Here's how `Board()` would look after using an array.

```
Board() {
    // creates the panel
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

    buttons = new JButton[9];
    for (int i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new JButton("");
    }

    SetGame();

    for (int i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        add(buttons[i]);    
        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
    }    
}
```

See how much shorter and less repetitive that is?

As a side note, by not specifying 'public' or 'private', you implicitly made your constructors package-private, which is rarely the right solution. I recommend specifying everything as either public or private, until you get to the point of distributing your code or compiled programs, in which case package-private might occasionally make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information :) I had a similar idea in mind because i wanted minimum repetition. But i was not sure about the implementation :)

Answer (score 7):

That's some nice code!  And welcome to Code Review.

1. It's [customary](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.2-class-names) to name variables and methods starting with lowercase and classes starting with uppercase.  This way you can easily tell which is which.  So for example:

   ```
   public class Control extends JFrame { // fine as is - classes are capitalized
   ```

   ```
   GameBoard = new Board(); // "gameBoard" should be lowercase
   ```

   ```
   private JButton Exit, Reset; // "exit" and "reset" should be lowercase
   ```

   ```
   public class Tic_Tac_Adv { // should be "TicTacAdv"
   ```
2. There's a lot of blank lines.  Is that intentional?

**Nit-picky stuff**

1. `package tic_tac_adv;`

   When you are more comfortable with Java you'll want to make a package name that NO ONE else is using.  The traditional way to do this is to use a website that you or your company controls, in reverse order.

   For example:

   ```
   package com.mycompany.games.tictactoe;
   ```

Ok, I guess that's it.  When you get more advanced you can use loops in your `WinCheck` method.  So instead of testing eight things, you can use one loop to check all the rows, a second loop to check all the columns, and then you check both diagonals.  For 3x3 Tic-Tac-Toe it doesn't really matter, but I think you can see how a loop would make things much easier if you were doing 4x4 or 5x5!

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) I'll keep all these tips and Suggestion in mind and make changes in WinCheck();. Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to disagree with "It looks very clean". There really need to be loops for code like this, otherwise it is not clean.

Comment: I just removed that one sentence.  I don't really have the time/energy to do a whole rewrite.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a for-loop inside your `actionPerformed` method.

```
for (int button = 0; button <= 8; button++) {
    if (pressed == buttons[button]) {
        GArray.arrayInitialize(button / 3, button % 3, playerMark);
        setText(pressed, player);
        playerMark = switchTurn(player);
        buttonDisabler(pressed);
    }
}
```

An important trick here is that you can calculate the `x` and `y` positions of your buttons with a bit of math. By using `button / 3` and `button % 3`.

Your `SwithTurn` method (which should be named `switchTurn`) is a bit ugly. It can be improved like this:

```
public int SwithTurn(boolean last) {
    player = !last;
    if (last) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

For the return, you can also use the *conditional operator*:

```
return last ? 1 : 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you don't need:

```
Control c = new Control();
```

You can just use:

```
new Control();
```

For this program

Answer (score 0):

@raptortech97 Loops were a great improvement :)

```
   package tic_tac_adv;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JButton Buttons[];
private GameArray GArray; // Class with Array
private boolean Player = false;
private int PlayerMark = 1;

/*
 Player is the Current players turn. if false player 1 will play else player 2
 PlayerMark is to set number to the array "1" for player 1 and "2" for player 2
 */
Board() {

    // creates the panel
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

    Buttons = new JButton[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.length; i++) {
        Buttons[i] = new JButton("");
    }

    SetGame();

    for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.length; i++) {
        Buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        add(Buttons[i]);
    }


}

public void SetGame() {

    GArray = new GameArray(this);

    DefaultText();
    DisableAll(true);

    Player = false; // default Value
    PlayerMark = 1; // default Value
}

public void Reset() {

    SetGame(); // To Reset the Game

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E) {

    JButton Pressed = (JButton) E.getSource();

    /*
     if any button is pressed the value is sent to GameArray class
     */
    if (Pressed == Buttons[0]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(0, 0, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);     // chaneg button text to "X" or "O" based on player turn
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player); // Swithch Turns
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[0]); // Disable pressed Button

    } else if (Pressed == Buttons[1]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(0, 1, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[1]);
    } else if (Pressed == Buttons[2]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(0, 2, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[2]);

    } else if (Pressed == Buttons[3]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(1, 0, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[3]);

    } else if (Pressed == Buttons[4]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(1, 1, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[4]);

    } else if (Pressed == Buttons[5]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(1, 2, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[5]);
    } else if (Pressed == Buttons[6]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(2, 0, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[6]);
    } else if (Pressed == Buttons[7]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(2, 1, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[7]);
    } else if (Pressed == Buttons[8]) {
        GArray.ArrayInitialize(2, 2, PlayerMark);
        SetText(Pressed, Player);
        PlayerMark = SwithTurn(Player);
        ButtonDisabler(Buttons[8]);
    }

}

public int SwithTurn(boolean last) {

    // if the past player was false(player 1) then swith to true(player 2)

    if (last == true) {
        Player = false;
        return 1;

    } else if (last == false) {
        Player = true;
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }

}

public void ButtonDisabler(JButton Btn) {

    Btn.setEnabled(false); // Disable Button

}

public void DisableAll(boolean Opp) {

            // Disable  All Buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.length; i++) {
        Buttons[i].setEnabled(Opp);
    }

}

public void SetText(JButton Btn, boolean Play) {

    if (Play == true) {
        Btn.setText("O");
    } else if (Play == false) {
        Btn.setText("X");
    }

}

public void DefaultText() {

    for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.length; i++) {
        Buttons[i].setText("");
    }
}

}
```